# Cannot format userdata, Fastboot refuses to detect

Tags: samsung, fastboot, formatting, lineageos

I have an OpenSUSE Leap 42.2, with adb, fastboot, and heimdall all present. My Android tablet is a Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 (model: SM-T713). I am attempting to flash Lineage OS onto it.

I have already flashed TWRP onto the tablet via heimdall, but TWRP fails to mount /data. It continuously spits out errors along the lines of `E: Can't mount /data (invalid argument)` and `Couldn't mount /data, and cannot find crypto folder.`

After some research, I discovered a solution is to run `fastboot format userdata` to erase the /data partition.

However, `fastboot format userdata` hangs:

```
$ fastboot format userdata
< waiting for device>
```

My tablet is in download mode, and is plugged in to the computer via USB. `lsusb` detects it, but `adb devices` and `fastboot devices` cannot detect it.

**Is there any way to allow Fastboot to format my tablet?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an unofficial release of TWRP, as at the time there was no official release. However, the official release for my device added an "Erase Data" button, which allowed me to succesfully flash Lineage.